# WebMethod CacheDuration - Avoid Caching Bad Results

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching, asmx

How can you avoid caching an error result with ASP/ASMX WebMethod with a CacheDuration property?

Let's say you have a WebMethod that adds two numbers (so it has two number parameters) and also has an account ID parameter. If say the account ID is an expired account, the answer to those 3 parameters would be "Error: Expired Account". If you have a cache duration of 10 minutes, if the account gets fixed in 1 minute, and that method is called again within 10 minute expiration period (with same 3 parameters), doesn't it return the error message that is cached?

Is there a way to avoid caching a result if it's an error message?

Comment: FYI, ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Yes, well aware. Don't care. I don't like WCF.

Comment: Have you tried WCF in .NET 4.5? Far simpler to use. And, BTW, Microsoft isn't even fixing bugs in ASMX.

Comment: Oh dear God, let the WCF crusade end. I'm not using it.

Comment: Hey, it's up to you. Most people like the vendor to fix bugs. Which Microsoft doesn't do for ASMX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying  on CacheDuration property you can do caching by yourself in webmethod. In that case you will have full control.

You can create unique cache key based on input parameter and store result in the cache (for specific duration) if there is no error.

So when there is error it means there is no cache, so you will again check if account is valid. And put result in cache if account valid.